# Show that zero sets of certain polynomials are connected in $\mathbb{C}P^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $C_d$ denote the zero set of $x^d + y^d + z^d + w^d$ in $\mathbb{C}P^3$.  What is a nice elementary way for me to see that $C_d$ is connected?

Comment: You can try to show it is irreducible. This will imply it is connected. See Griffiths and Harris, page 21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the partial derivatives of $x^d + y^d + z^d + w^d$ do not vanish at any point of $C_d$, that last hypersurface is smooth.
Now just use the fact that a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb P^n(\mathbb C)$ 
($n \geq 3$) is connected (and even simply connected) to conclude: [Griffiths-Harris](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471050598.html) page 159, lines 12 to 14.
More generally a smooth complete intersection of dimension $\geq 2$ in projective space  $\mathbb P^n(\mathbb C)$ is connected and simply connected.
All these results (and more) go under  labels like "Lefschetz theorems on hyperplane sections".